# показ и сокрытие div по клику одного из 100

Tags: javascript, php, css

Есть блок с данными - единый шаблон для всех однотипных. Таких блоков на сайте может быть до 100.
При клике на крестик происходит добавление классов, сам крестик поворачивается и открывается ранее скрытый блок.
Но изменения происходят сразу во всех однотипных блоках.
Как можно ограничить выполнение команды только тем блоком, в котором выполнен клик?

введите сюда код

```
$(biochrist).click(function () {
    var activeBioClass = 'open';

    $(biochrist).toggleClass(activeBioClass);
    $(speaker__bio).toggleClass(activeBioClass);
});

.speaker__photo-btn {
  background-color: black;
  right: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
.speaker__photo-btn_link {
  position: relative;
  transition: .3s all;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.speaker__bio {
  display: none;
}  
.speaker__photo-btn_link.open {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: 300ms;
}
.speaker__photo-btn_link:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 8px;
}
.speaker__photo-btn_link:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 8px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.speaker__bio.open {
  display: block;
}


<div class="speaker">
    <div class="speaker__photo">
        <?php echo  wp_get_attachment_image($speaker['photo'], 'medium_large') ?>
        <div class="speaker__photo-btn">
             <div class="speaker__photo-btn_link biochrist" id="biochrist"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="speaker__text">
        <h4><?php echo $speaker['name'] ?></h4>
        <div class="speaker__capture">
            <?php echo $speaker['desciption'] ?>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="speaker__bio" id="speaker__bio">
         <?php echo $speaker['bio'] ?>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(biochrist).click(function () {
    var activeBioClass = 'open';

    $(this).toggleClass(activeBioClass);
    $(this).closest('.speaker').find(speaker__bio).toggleClass(activeBioClass);
});
```

---

```
$(biochrist).click(function () {
    let activeBioClass = 'open';
    let wasOpen = $(this).hasClass(activeBioClass);

    $('.biochrist.open').removeClass(activeBioClass);
    $('.speaker__bio.open').removeClass(activeBioClass);

    if (!wasOpen) {
      $(this).addClass(activeBioClass);
      $(this).closest('.speaker').find(speaker__bio).addClass(activeBioClass);
    }
});
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! В рамках моего вопроса - идеально! Есть еще один вопрос: Теперь если я кликаю на элемент - выплывает скрытый блок, кликаю второй раз - он уплывает. Все, как и нужно. Но если я не кликаю второй раз, но кликаю на соседний - он тоже срабатывает. При этом первый остается открытым. Как бы сделать, чтобы при клике на второй - первый бы закрывался?

Comment: Все вопросы решены! Еще раз огромное спасибо! Вы- Мастер! Когда я этому сам научусь?(((

Comment: @Alandr Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.